# how to return a string from a function which is listening some stream in dart?

Tags: dart, stdout

i have a function called foo which is listening to the stdout, what i want is to return some string which i got from stdout. here is my function;

```
    dynamic foo(process) {
  return (
    process.stdout.transform(UTF8.decoder).listen((data) {
    String s = data.toString();
    // print(s);
    if (s.contains("received event of")) {
      var s1 = s.split(":");

      print("${s1[1]}");
      return s1[1];
    }
  }));
}
```

I want to return s1 to the calling function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want

```
Future<String> dynamic foo(process) {
  return process.stdout.transform(UTF8.decoder).map((data) {
    String s = data.toString();
    // print(s);
    if (s.contains("received event of")) {
      var s1 = s.split(":");

      print("${s1[1]}");
      return s1[1];
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }).where((val) => val != null).first;
}
```

Your custom code either returns a valid value or `null`.
I changed `listen` to `map` to be able to use additional stream methods.
`where` filters invalid values (`null`) and returns the first non-`null` value.

The caller of the `foo` method needs to handle the returned `Future` (using for example `async`/`await`) to get the value when it becomes available.

Use it like

```
bar() async {
  ...
  var input = await foo(proc);
  print(input);
}
```

Comment: i got your point but future return only once  but i have return to called function whenever data is available. well i got a solution and i am sharing it now by the way thanks for response

Comment: Just remove `.first` and fix the return type to `Stream<String>` and on the call site use `.listen(...)` or `await for(var input of foo(proc)) { ... }`

Comment: getting this `Class '_Future' has no instance method 'listen'.`

Comment: Sounds like you didn't remove `.first`

Comment: sorry, my bad with return type, great work and  thanks for the fix

Answer (score 2):

here a callback function do the trick

```
 foo(process, callback) {
    process.stdout.transform(UTF8.decoder).listen((data) {
      String s = data.toString();
      if (s.contains("received event of")) {
        String message = s.split(":")[1];
        callback(message);
      }
    });
  }
```

and here i am calling the method and printing the data which i get get from stream.

```
foo(process,(data){print(data);})
```

Comment: Honestly, that's quite ugly. That's exactly what Dart allows you to avoid by providing stream. `someStream.listen(callback)` allows you to use this in a universal and composable way and provide operators like `where` and many others to process events. See the last comment below my answer for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I think that everybody wants this:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert';

// Using system encoding:
var outputStr = await process.stdout.transform(systemEncoding.decoder).join();

// Using UTF-8 encoding:
var outputStr = await process.stdout.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
```

Comment: That is absolutely what I wanted! Thanks! :)